# Из Java на Kotlin (Plugin)

Tags: java, kotlin, плагин

Как перенести код на Kotlin

### Java

```
public class XXX extends TextComponentEditorAction {

    public XXX (EditorActionHandler defaultHandler) {
        super(defaultHandler);
    }

    public XXX () {
        this(new Handler());
    }

    private static class Handler extends EditorWriteActionHandler {
        private Handler() {
        }
    @Override
        public void executeWriteAction(final Editor editor, @Nullable Caret caret, DataContext dataContext) {

     // Какой то код
    
    }
```

Так же есть класс с plugin.xml

```
<actions>
    <!-- Add your actions here -->
    <action id="com.tm.XXX" class="com.tm.XXX" text="XXXxxx" description="XXX xx xx">
      <add-to-group group-id="EditorActions" anchor="last"/>
      <keyboard-shortcut keymap="$default" first-keystroke="ctrl alt NUMPAD5"/>
    </action>
  </actions>
```

Пробовал несколько вариантов но так как конструктор должен быть без параметров, не пойму как это реализовать на kotlin

### Kotlin

```
class XXX (defaultHandler: EditorActionHandler) : TextComponentEditorAction(defaultHandler) {

    init {
       Handler()
    }
    
    class Handler() : EditorWriteActionHandler() {
```

ругается на то что  class="com.tm.XXX" должен иметь пустой конструктор. Как это можно победить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В java у Вас 2 конструктора, в kotlin можно обойтись одним + добавить аннотацию [@JvmOverloads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/) для перегрузки конструктора.

```
class XXX @JvmOverloads constructor(defaultHandler: EditorActionHandler = Handler()) : TextComponentEditorAction(defaultHandler)
```

Что тут происходит, мы объявляем главный конструктор в котором инициализируем `defaultHandler`, инициализация нужна для того, чтобы в случае создания экземпляра класса без передачи аргументов в конструктор у нас было значение по умолчанию, если мы при создании экземпляра класса передадим в качестве аргумента другой `Handler()`, то он перезапишет значение по умолчанию у defaultHandler. `@JvmOverloads` создаст перегруженные версии конструктора, в том числе и пустой.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!